# If Statement with date

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

I am doing an assignment for school, and I get bonus marks if I add a discount on a certain day. I have an actively updating time, using the date function(is it a function?) but I don't know how I would go about making an if statement for this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $t = time();
    echo "Date of Purchase: " . (date("Y-m-d", $t));

    if(date == "20140224") {
        echo $b;
        echo "It works!";
    }
?>
```

Obviously I only provided relevant code. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime()` as DateTime objects are comparable:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$discountDate = new DateTime('2014-02-24');
if ($today == $discountDate) {
   // today is discount day!
}
```

Tip: No need to use `time()` to pass a second parameter to `date()`. `date()` always assumes "now" when no second parameter is passed

Comment: I tried this, what you did word for word basically, yetI cant echo the $today, or compare the discount date and today

Comment: How do you want the date to be print out? What format?

Comment: Coode yes i do, I would like it to print out yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but the idea is that you have a function with parameters.

```
function getPrice($price, $search_date, $happyDays=5) {

    if(date('w', strtotime($search_date)) == $happyDays) {
      return $price * 0.8; // 20% discount
    } else {
      return $price; // full price
    }

}
```

Call it like so:

```
echo "Sum: " . getPrice(100, $_SESSION['purchase_date']);
```

Ps. I use a session date value, since I think the customer should get the discount if he/she places the order just before midnight :-) (as long as the session is still alive).