# PHP strotime check + 10days to the first day of the next month

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to check if the end of the month is within 10 days. If not, the date should be the first day of the following month. If the end of the month is within the next ten days, then I need to display first day of the month following next month.

Here is my code:

```
$tenDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+10 days'));
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('$tenDays, first day of next month'));

echo"$tenDays";
echo "<br>";
echo "$firstDayNextMonth";
```

The output is:

> 2015-08-01
>   1970-01-01

Based on the date today `2015-07-22` the desired outcome for the second line should be `2015-09-01`, not `1970-01-01`.

Comment: strtotime looks like a magic, but there is not a magic, it has a syntax..

Comment: Use a timestamp as the 2nd parameter for `strtotime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `strtotime()` for date math. That's *not* what it is there for. Use `DateTime()`.

```
$firstDayNextMonth = (new DateTime('+10 days'))->modify('first day of next month')->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/403585)

Comment: datetime uses the same logic internally as strtotime for most of that "arbitrary date-in-english" stuff, however.

Comment: @John Conde. Many thanks for the reply and help. It worked perfectly. I am new to PHP. You said not to use strtotime() for date math. In another part of my code I am testing if the date one month from now is equal to a date stored in my database. Is strtotime() sufficient purpose?Here is my code: $num = date("Y-m-d");
// Current Date + 1 Month
$enum = strtotime("$num +1 month");
// String to Date
$stnum = strtotime($num);
$stend = strtotime($cjenddat); //$cjenddat value from database
// If statement to check if clients end date is 1 month from current date
if($enum == $stend){//do stuff}

Comment: `DateTime()` is great for [comparing dates, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999879/if-statement-with-date/21999917#21999917). It's just more readable and flexible.

Comment: Thanks.I used your example as a template and changed that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `00` as the day-of-month:

```
$foo = new DateTime('2015-03-00');
$foo->format('r');
```

As you can see, the `0th` of March, is the last day of February. So a simple `$foo->format('d')` will get you that last-day-of-month.